# How to stop view to refresh when partial loads in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I click on Partial View element on `tab` click like `India` then the whole view is getting refreshed. I tried using `Ajax` but control does not even hit there. Where I am doing wrong, can anyone please guide me?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ClsHome model = new ClsHome();

    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult EmployeeBasedCountry(int CountryId)
{
    ClsHome clshome = new ClsHome();
    clshome.Country = CountryId;

    clshome.countries = CountryFilter(CountryId);          
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_pEmp.cshtml", clshome);
}
```

View

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome      

<div id=Partial class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>
```

Partial

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome  
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("India", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new {@class = "ActionLinkId", @CountryId = "1" },null)
    </li> 
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new {@class = "ActionLinkId", @CountryId = "2" },null)</li>       
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="panel">
        <table class="table-striped">
            <tr class="heading">
                <th>
                    EmpId
                </th>
                <th>
                    EmpName
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.EmpId
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a>@item.EmpName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ActionLinkId').on("click", function () {
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                       url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home")',
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { data }
                    })
                        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                            debugger;
                            $("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);
                        });
                });
            });
```

Comment: You used `ActionLink` that it causes refresh page. You can use `ajax` to prevent refresh.

Comment: @AliSoltani, how to do this. I just followed below solution but still my script does not fire.

Comment: You do not have an element with `class="ActionLinkId"` - your `@Html.ActionLink()` is adding that as a route value. You need to add it in the 5th argument of `ActionLink()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your comment. As 5th argument is null so how can i do this?

Comment: Its `@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { CountryId = 2 }, new { @class = "ActionLinkId" })`

Comment: @MVC as in my answer 5 minutes ago... :)

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thank you for your answer. But How to use this in `Ajax`. I have to pass `CountryId`. I think my script is not correct. can you please help me.

Comment: That's a different question.  In your ajax: `url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { CountryId = $(this).attr("countryid") })',` - but you should change that to `data-countryid` and `$(this).data("countryid")`

Comment: @freedomn-m, I can't write `new { CountryId = $(this).attr("countryid") }` inside this block. It is giving me error.

Comment: @MVC, NO! Look at the html your are generating - you do not have a attribute named `countryid`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I changed `countryid` to `CountryId`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry to ask you. Can you please help me to write `Ajax` for this.

Comment: What? - do as @freedomn-m as noted. Add a `data-countryid` attribute to you link and get in in the ajax call using `var id = $(this).data("countryid")`

Comment: Or you can simply use `var url = $(this).attr('href')` and delete the `data` option

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I used like this `url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { data-CountryId = $(this).attr("CountryId") })',` which gives me error `'_Page_Views_Home__pEmp_cshtml' does not contain a definition for 'attr' and no extension method 'attr' accepting a first argument of type '_Page_Views_Home__pEmp_cshtml' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You're right - my code earlier was incorrect.  You can't use `$(this)` inside `@Url.Action`.  Better to go with @StephenMuecke 's option of getting the url from the link directly:  `url: $(this).attr("href"),`

Comment: @freedomn-m, If I use `url: $(this).attr("href")` then how does it fires the controller code. I mean how can we pass `CountryId` value inside Controller. Also Please help me to modify `data: { data }` which gives me error

Comment: You use the href of the link (`$(this)`) which will already have the country on the url - use the "or split them" version in my answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I used "or split them" version.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, `<div id=Partial class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>` displays 2 partials. And I removed `data: { data }` from script. Where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @freedomn-m,  Partial code is generating 2 partials. Also, even If i click on `USA` tab, it still shows `India`.

Comment: @MVC This question was (essentially): jquery event not getting triggered.  This was because your arguments were wrong to ActionLink.  Changing the ActionLink now fires your event which stops the page reloading (caused by the link).  This answers your question (as confirmed by having new issues).  If you have further questions, please feel free to create a new question with where you have got to so far as it's now very muddied.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thank you for your comment. I will post a new question.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Can you please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590457/why-my-partial-is-rendering-2-times-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment90146868_51590457)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Please help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592547/how-to-implement-ul-nav-tabs-to-behave-like-a-data-toggle-tab-href-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your parameters around the wrong way for `@Html.ActionLink`

```
@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", 
                 new { @class = "ActionLinkId", @CountryId = "2" }, 
                 null)
```

this overload is: `linktext, action, controller, routeValues, htmlAttributes`  where htmlAttributes is `null` so your rendered `<a>` does not have these attributes.

Easy enough to check your *rendered* html which will be like:

```
<a href="/Home/EmployeeBasedCountry?class=ActionLinkId&countryId=2">USA</a>
```

So your link doesn't have the `.ActionLinkId` class, so the jquery doesn't fire.  Also easy enough to check with:

```
$(function() { alert($(".ActionLinkId").length) });
```

(or use browser debugger *earlier*)

Fix is to remove the `null` at the end:

```
@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new {@class = "ActionLinkId", @CountryId = "2" })
```

or split them, depending on the requirement

```
@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "2" }, new {@class = "ActionLinkId" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please help me to simplify my script.

Answer (score 2):

When you're clicking the link, the ajax request sent, but the link do its action, too, and refrsh the page. So, you should prevent the browser from refrsh the page (For more information see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)):

```
$('.ActionLinkId').on("click", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event; // To support old browsers
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("TabLeadingSires", "Home")',
    type: "GET",
    data: { data }
  }).done(function(partialViewResult) {
    $("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);
  });
});
```

Comment: script still does not fire.

Comment: This is like @freedomn-m, beacuse you pass the parameter to HTML helper in wrong order.

Comment: I changed the code according to @freedomn-m noted. But the partial is rendering 2 times.

Comment: This is beacuse what I said, both the link and the ajax request are send.

Comment: Then how I can achieve my requirements.

Comment: Write the Raozor code like @freedomn-m - `@Html.ActionLink("USA", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { CountryId = "2"  }, new { @class = "ActionLinkId" })`, and your JS code like me.

Comment: I did the same way you did. and I removed ` data: { data }`  from script. As you have seen, When first loads, it executes the partial and loads the data. Now when I click on any of the tab then another set of partial renders along with previously generated partial.

Comment: What do you say? The new partial doesn't replace the previous partial?

Comment: No. It is creating new one.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
   @Html.ActionLink("India", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new {@class = "ActionLinkId", @CountryId = "1" }
```

which is used to load page... just use class or id parameter to invoke ajax.

Comment: How to do this? Can you please provide an answer for this.

Comment: <button id="fire" value="1">India</button>
$('.fire').on("click", function(e) {
//your code here
}
try like this... you can get element by id if you wanna get some parameter.....