# Why my partial is rendering 2 times in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial which initially renders when the page first loads. And then When I click on `nav-tab`, it creates another set of `partial` inside my View. It should update the same partial without creating a new set of it.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ClsHome model = new ClsHome();

    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult EmployeeBasedCountry(int CountryId)
{
    ClsHome clshome = new ClsHome();
    clshome.Country = CountryId;

    clshome.countries = CountryFilter(CountryId);          
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_pEmp.cshtml", clshome);
}
```

View

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome      

<div id=Partial class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>
```

Partial

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome  
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Australia", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new  @CountryId = "1" },new{@class = "ActionLinkId"})
    </li> 
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Zealand", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new {@CountryId = "2" },new{@class = "ActionLinkId"})</li>       
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="panel">
        <table class="table-striped">
            <tr class="heading">
                <th>
                    EmpId
                </th>
                <th>
                    EmpName
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.EmpId
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a>@item.EmpName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).on("click", '.ActionLinkId', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),        
            type: "GET",
        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            debugger;
            $("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);
        });
        });
```

Comment: Did you check if there is no other div with the id partial ?

Comment: Div ID in your view needs quotation marks

Comment: @CoskunOzogul, Yes I checked it. There is no other div with id Partial.

Comment: @James, I tried that as well. No luck.

Comment: Try putting `$('#Partial').children().remove();` before `$("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);`. This removes all previous child elements from the partial div, then renders AJAX result.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I tried your code as well. But still it is generating 2 partials.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, `$('#Partial').children().remove();` worked for me now. Now can you please guide me even I click on `New Zealand` from `nav-tab`, it is still showing `Australia` in front end.

Comment: If you want to handle `li` tab click, handle `$('.nav li')` click event and use `$('.nav li').not(this).removeClass('active')` & add `$(this).addClass('active')`. And as for your `ActionLink`, use `Ajax.ActionLink` with `InsertionMode.Replace`: `@Ajax.ActionLink("New Zealand", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { @CountryId = "2" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Partial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "ActionLinkId" })`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I did `$('.nav li').click(function () {
            $('.nav li').not(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });` but still not working. It changed for a second then flips back to `Australia`

Comment: Your Code looks fine. I think you are not getting correct html from you controller write `console.log(partialViewResult)` before updating `HTML` and check on console tab that you are getting correct html or not.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have `class=col-md-5` implies this is not *all* of your HTML in the view.

While it's useful to provide a cut-down snippet, this could be the cause of getting "two contents" when reloading via ajax - especially if you have a bootstrap modal dialog or similar.  I suggest in the first case to reduce the html to the bare minimum.

The reason your tabs are not updating is because you are replacing too much.  You are including the tabs in your PartialView so they are being overwritten when you replace them.  So what happens is:

- initial render
- click on `li` - bootstrap selects it (so you see it for a moment)
- your ajax GET code runs
- the `li` is overwritten with your hardcoded `li class=active` (so resets back)

The key is to move the navigation to *outside* the content, ie:

View:
    @model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Australia", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new  CountryId = "1" }, new { @class = "ActionLinkId" })
    </li> 
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Zealand", "EmployeeBasedCountry", "Home", new { CountryId = "2" }, new { @class = "ActionLinkId"})</li>       
</ul>

<div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="panel">
            <div id="Partial">
                @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome  
<table class="table-striped">
    ...
```

then your "navigation" remains on the page and is not reloaded/reset each time.

An alternative to would be to set the "active" only on the correct `li`, but that gets messy and mixes separation of concerns (your partial should be concerned only with rendering the content, not the navigation).

Comment: I followed your answer but now the partial is not rendering into the page.

Comment: Can't I use like this `<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="NZTab">`

Comment: You might need to move where `col-md-5` is - I've updated the code to put it back where it would have been

Comment: I moved `id="Partial"` to `<div id="Partial" class='col-md-5'>` but still not working. I think `<ul>` code under main view is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cause in this case must be returning a view instead of a partial view.
In your case, the view will come with the layout code.

Try to add a new view and check it as partial view, copy your code into this view, it must work.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that I am returning partial view from controller and it also executes in Main View.

Comment: In your partial controller, you return a partial view, it is sure. Once, I forgot to check 'PartialView' my view at the moment of adding into my project. That is why I believe that it must be a view. In your code, I didn't see any anomaly.