# How to implement <ul> nav-tabs to behave like <a data-toggle="tab" href="#"> in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement my `<li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("CAN", "Emp", "Home", new { @CountryId = "1" }, new { @class = "LinkId" })</li>` like `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#">`. Currently, If I am selecting any `Tab` it is showing `CAN` only. How to change this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ClsHome model = new ClsHome();

    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult Emp(int CountryId)
{
    ClsHome clshome = new ClsHome();
    clshome.Country = CountryId;

    clshome.countries = CountryFilter(CountryId);          
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_pEmp.cshtml", clshome);
}
```

View

```
@model EmpWebsite.Models.Home.ClsHome      

<div id=Partial class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>
```

partial

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("CAN", "Emp", "Home", new { @CountryId = "1" }, new { @class = "LinkId" })</li>
     <li> 
        @Html.ActionLink("FR", "Emp", "Home", new { @CountryId = "2" }, new { @class = "LinkId" })</li>      
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="panel">
            <table class="table-striped">
                <tr class="heading">
                    <th>
                        EmpId
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        EmpName
                    </th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.EmpId
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a>@item.EmpName</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
$(document).on("click", '.LinkId', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),        
            type: "GET",
        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            debugger;
            $("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);
        });
        });
```

Comment: So - You want the @Html.ActionLink to generate a link like `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#">`?

Comment: @Adriani6, I want `@Html.ActionLink` behave like `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#">`.

Comment: Then don't create an ActionLink. Why can't you just use the html you've literally posted? That will solve your issue.

Comment: But I have to send `CountryId` to my controller so that reason I have created Link.

Comment: @Adriani6, I want this Link to behave like `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#A">A</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#B">B</a></li>               
                </ul> 
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="A" class="tab-pane fade">
                        //
                    </div>
                   
                        <div id="B" class="tab-pane fade  in active"></div>

                      </div>`

Comment: So decide what you want. How can `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#">` behave the same as `<a href="/Controller/Method?CountryId=1">` that your ActionLink represents? Why are you sending CountryId to your controller? Maybe it's a good place to put an ajax call in place and keep your old way of creating a tab?

Comment: @Adriani6, I have to pass `CountryId` into controller to populate the data. So please suggest me the better way.

Comment: Make an ajax call. Then add the contents of the ajax call back to that tab. Plenty of resources on how to make ajax calls on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Adriani6, I have edited my question. Can you please show me how to do that. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did almost everything you need - in this case you don't need server-side programming to achieve the wanted result, just use Javascript or jQuery in your case.

I don't know what exactly would you like to achieve, but you can give a go with the following code snippets.

**View**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="LinkId" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/home/emp?CountryID=1" data-id="1">CAN</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="LinkId" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/home/emp?CountryID=2" data-id="2">FR</a>
  </li>     
</ul>  

<div id=Partial class="col-md-5">                 
   @Html.Partial("_pEmp")
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on("click", '.LinkId', function (e) {
            var $link = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data("url"),        
            type: "GET",
        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $('.LinkId.active').removeClass('active');
            $link.addClass('active');

            debugger;
            $("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);
        });
 });
```

Comment: Do I have to provide  some Name inside href `<a href="#"`. As I am using the same model to populate the data. Just I need to send CountryId to Controller code.

Comment: @MVC Since your controller needs only one parameter you only need to pass CountryID.

Comment: If I do not pass anything in href then once click on CAN or FR, it throws error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #`

Comment: please help me here.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code then. Check the syntax; try to debug it first.

Comment: It is not hitting the controller as well. It is not going inside `$.ajax({`

Comment: Also, if I put `#` inside `href` then it doesnot even hit the script

Comment: @It throws error `The parameter dictionary contains a null entry for parameter `CountryId` of non-nullable type` And controller is not hitting.

Comment: Check the changes

Comment: `$("#Partial").html(partialViewResult);` after this line of code, it moves back to 1st Country Tab. When I click on 2nd Tab then it should be there.

Comment: @MVC That is because you are returning partial view with those tabs. Try removing them from the partial view and implement them somewhere outside of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177052/discussion-between-weglagerer-and-mvc).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution really helped me.

Comment: @MVC I'm glad I helped you ;)